# WPF bottun rounded corner

Tags: wpf, button, border

So i have this `"window"` (not a `Window` but `Grid`):

[image]

Code:

```
<Grid Name="gridDeleteAllWindows">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="110"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Label Content="Delete All Files"
                       FontSize="20"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <Label Content="Are you sure you want to remove"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <Label Content="all the files ?"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#55B3B3B6">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="#55B3B3B6" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Name="btnDeleteAllFilesYes"
                                Content="Yes"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Style="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Click="btnDeleteAllFilesYes_Click"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderBrush="#55B3B3B6" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Name="btnDeleteAllFilesNo"
                                Content="No"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Style="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Click="btnDeleteAllFilesNo_Click"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroFlatButton}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF103766"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF6899D3"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        x:Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And i want just to add another `color` into my `Button` while `MouseEnter` so i add this `Trigger`:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>
```

Result:

[image]

And as you can see that my rounded corner is now missing so i just need your help to fix it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what does it do ?

Comment: Well ... it solves your problem !

Comment: Yes but how cause i need only the lower left side

Comment: Apply that opacity mask at your root element.